# PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing накладывает изображения в одну ячейку

Tags: php

```
$logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();

$logo->setPath($imagePath);

$logo->setCoordinates("A".$i);       
$logo->setWorksheet($sheet);
```

В общем есть такой вот код для вставки изображений в excel, он рабочий, в цикле в документ вставляются изображения но доходя до определенной строчки N все последующие изображения начинают накладываться друг на друга в одну ячейку, в чем может быть проблема ? с циклом проблем нет координаты не повторяются. Но  самое интересное то что если потом в документе мышкой сделать меньше или шире или выше любую ячейку то все картинки сразу сами расставляются по своим местам...